# MongoDB - Mongoose: How Do I Update Simultaneously Two Separate Embedded Documents With Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

So I am trying to update the field `status` in my `Report` document and in my `Station.reports` sub-document which is an array of objects, in one single API call. The issue is that I am able to update the Report document, but not the station document when making the API call. After the call, the `console.log(station.reports);` returns the expected subdocument which is : `[{"_id":"588fed278b50cd180bd6cc15","date":"2017-01-31T01:48:57.487Z","status":"Archived"}]` But this is not saved in the corresponding Station document in my DB. Please I need help here. Thanks.

**Station Document:**

```
{
    "_id": "588a777d4e26720e7afa7e1e",
    "phone": "(007) – 007 – 7007",
    "name": "name1",
    "email": "name1@email.com",
    "reports": [
      {
        "status": "Submitted",
        "date": "2014-01-31T01:48:57.487Z",
        "_id": "588fed278b50cd180bd6cc15"
      }
    ]
}
```

**Report Document**

```
{
    "_id": "588fed278b50cd180bd6cc15",
    "description": "Description of the report",
    "time": "05:48 PM",
    "date": "2017-01-31T01:48:57.487Z",
    "status": "Archived",
    "location" : "123 Main Street"
    "station" : "588a777d4e26720e7afa7e1e"
}
```

**API Call**

```
router.put('/reports/:id/updateStatus', function (req, res) {

    Report.findById(req.params.id, function(err,report){
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
        // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
          return res.send(err);

        //  Update the Report object 
        report.status = req.body.status;

        // Update the Corresponding station.reports subdocument
        Station.findOne({_id:report.station}, function (err, data) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);

            data.reports.forEach(function(rpt){
                if (rpt._id == req.params.id){

                    rpt.status = req.body.status
                    data.save(function (err, station) {
                        if (err)
                            return res.send(err); 

                        console.log(station.reports);
                    })
                }
            })
        })

        report.save(function (err, report) {
            if (err)
                return res.send(err); 

            res.json(report);
        })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts, and with the help of Ravi, I was able to figure out a solution that worked for me pretty well. The only thing that changed was my `API` call. The rest of the code was unchanged.
 Hope this helps someone having similar needs.

**API CALL**

```
router.put('/reports/:id/updateStatus', function (req, res) {

    Report.findById(req.params.id, function(err,report){
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
        // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
          return res.send(err);

        //  Update the Report object 
        report.status = req.body.status;

        // Update the Corresponding station.reports subdocument
        Station.findOne({_id:report.station}, function (err, info) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);

            info.reports.forEach(function(rpt){
                if (rpt._id == req.params.id){

                    Station.update({_id:info._id, "reports._id":rpt._id },
                        {
                            $set:{"reports.$.status": req.body.status }
                        },function (err, results) {
                            if(err) return console.log("This Station couldn't be updated " + err);
                            console.log(results)
                        }
                    )
                }
            })
            report.save(function (err, report) {
                if (err)
                    return res.send(err); 

                res.json({report:report, station:info});
            });
        })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing mistake while updating the `station` object. Use `findOneAndUpdate` to find the matching `Station` document, and then change the status of the matched reports item(matched using reports._id).

Try this:

```
Station.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id:report.station,"reports._id":req.params.id
    },{
        $set : {reports.$.status : req.body.status}
    },function(err){
    if(err)
        return res.send(err);
});
```

`report._id` will find the array element whose `_id` is `req.params.id` and `report.$.status` will update only the matching element of the array.

For more information on `positional $(update) operator`, Read [mongoDB positional Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Also, i would suggest to `save` the `report` object in the `callback of update`. As `nodejs` is `asynchronous`, it will not wait for the `update` to finish, if you are saving `report` outside of the callback. And, you might get **Cant set the headers after they are sent** `error`. Thus, its recommended to do it in the callback.

Thus your **final API code** would look like:

```
router.put('/reports/:id/updateStatus', function (req, res) {

    Report.findById(req.params.id, function(err,report){
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
        // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
          return res.send(err);

        //  Update the Report object 
        report.status = req.body.status;

        // Update the Corresponding station.reports subdocument
        Station.findOneAndUpdate({
                "_id":report.station,"reports._id":req.params.id
            },{
                $set : {"reports.$.status" : req.body.status}
            },function(err, result){
                if(err)
                    return res.send(err);
                console.log(result);
                report.save(function (err, report) {
                    if (err)
                        return res.send(err); 

                    res.json(report);
                });
        });
    });
})
```

**UPDATE**
**Alternate Method**

Another way can be, You can proceed in the original way, but don't save the data inside the forEach, instead save the data sheet forEach finishes.

```
Station.findOne({_id:report.station}, function (err, data) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);

    data.reports.forEach(function(rpt){
        if (rpt._id == req.params.id){

            rpt.status = req.body.status
        }
    });
    data.save(function (err, station) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err); 

        console.log(station.reports);
        report.save(function (err, report) {
            if (err)
                return res.send(err);
            res.json(report);
        });
    })
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Ravi. Thanks for your reply. I would like to try your suggestion, but first given that the subdocument `reports`  is an array, how can you possibly write `"reports._id"`. This will probably break the whole thing right? Maybe I am missing something

Comment: No no, you can query in the array like that, and  `reports.$.status` will update only the matching element of the reports array

Comment: Really. I wasn't aware of that technique. Ok. Let me try it right now.

Comment: Tried it but it did't work. Still updates the `report` object, but not the `station.reports` subdocument. I even tried `$push` instead of `$set` no luck

Comment: Can you check if there is some error, but I think my Edited answer should work.

Comment: There is no error. the report object is being saved but not the updated station. I am using postman for testing purposes

Comment: See the changes in my Edited answer and then, tell me what console.log(result) prints. This will help solve the bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134566/discussion-between-alljs-and-ravi-shankar).

Comment: I have Edited the answer again, see if this one helps

Comment: Tried your new edit, no luck once again. I am very surprised none of the solutions works for me, even though they all make perfect sense!

Comment: There must be some problem in your data then. Can you show the snapshot of data? Try using tools like robomongo to have a look at how data is stored

Comment: I am using Cloud9 as my Dev environment and unfortunately I was unable to connect my database to Robomongo.

Comment: what data do you want to look at? `Report` or `Station (Organization)`

Comment: Station data I want to look at

Comment: `{
  "_id": "588a777d4e26720e7afa7e1e",
  "department": "58847023300fc521ffcbd5be",
  "phone": "(007) – 007 – 7007",
  "name": "name1",
  "email": "name1@email.com",
  "reports": [
    {
      "status": "Submitted",
      "date": "2017-01-31T01:48:57.487Z",
      "_id": "588fed278b50cd180bd6cc15"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: `var stationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name                : String,
    email               : String,
    phone               : String,
    department          : { 
        type            : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref             : 'department' 
    },
    reports             : []
})`

Comment: `stationSchema.methods.updateStatus = function (status) {
    var station = this;
    station.reports.forEach(function(rpt){
  if (rpt._id === station._id){
      
   rpt.status = status
   station.save()
  }
 })
}`

Comment: I attached a method to the station model, to see if it could directly save the status once updated, but I got the same thing at the end.

Comment: Can u show me how you are using the method? Also, please move the station.save() outside the forEach loop

Comment: `Station.findOne({_id:report.station}, function (err, info) {
 if(err) return console.log(err);

 info.updateStatus(req.body.status)
})`

Comment: Move the `station.save()` outside of the forEach loop and it should work

Comment: I did and it didn't.

Comment: Let's talk on chat